# 'habitaciones' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hola chicos soy nuevo por aquí y quisiera que por favor serian tan amables de ayudarme con este problemita. No puedo avanzar por este error soy muy novato en el tema pero he consultado y no he podido resolverlo. Lo que pretendo es mostrar los objetos (lista de habitaciones) que estoy creando desde el panel de administrador y decirle a la vista que los muestre en una plantilla HTML de uno en uno.

> **NOTA:** Estaba guiándome de un video de YouTube pero a la persona si le funciona correctamente y se le visualiza la información en la plantilla correspondiente. Si hay otra forma de hacerlo les agradecería

Dejo mi modelo:

```
class habitaciones(models.Model):

codigo = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)

HABITACIONES = Choices (

    ('INDIVIDUAL', _('Individual')),
    ('DOBLE DE USO INDIVIDUAL', _('Doble de Uso Individual')),
    ('DOBLE', _('Habitación Doble')),
    ('CON CAMA SUPLETORIA', _('Con cama Supletoria')),
    ('TRIPLE', _('Habitación Triple')),
    ('JUNIOR SUITE', _('Junior Suite')),
    ('SUITE', _('Suite')),
    ('SUITE NUPCIAL', _('Suit Nupcial')),
)

tipo_habitacion = models.CharField (max_length=25, choices=HABITACIONES, 
default=HABITACIONES.INDIVIDUAL)
imagen = models.ImageField(null=True)

precio = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
cupo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
nro_habitacion = models.IntegerField() 
caracteristicas = models.TextField(blank=True,help_text='Ingresa la descripción de la habitacion')

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Y la vista:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

from sistema.models import habitaciones

def habitacion_fuction(request):

habitacion = habitaciones.objects.all()
return render (request, 'sistema/habitaciones.html' , {'habitacion': habitacion})
```

template

```
   {% extends "sistema/base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

   {% for habitaciones in habitacion %}

<div><p>

   <h2>{{habitaciones.tipo_habitacion}}</h2>

<p>{{habitaciones.caracteristicas}}</p>


</p></div>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Hasta ahora eso es lo que quiero mostrar en el template. Lo que es el nombre de la habitación y las características. Después colocaría la imagen y el precio. No tiene estilos CSS aun pero eso lo colocaría despues.

----Error-----

```
 Environment:


 Request Method: GET
 Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/habitaciones

 Django Version: 3.1
 Python Version: 3.7.9
 Installed Applications:
 ['grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'sistema',
 'autenticacion']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Mi PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\Mi PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
response = self.process_response(request, response)
File "C:\Users\Mi PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /habitaciones
Exception Value: 'habitaciones' object has no attribute 'get'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿De que forma quieres mostrar los objetos en tu template? O quieres mostrarlos en el template tal como Python representa los objetos? Actualiza tu pregunta con los detalles, para ayudarte con mayor facilidad.

Comment: Gracias, ya actualice

Comment: Hola. Por favor, incluye el error completo. Me gustaría saber de dónde viene el error.

Comment: Hola Cesar, te adjunte información del error gracias.

Comment: Mira que hago el mismo procedimiento de traer todos los objetos desde consola interactiva ósea desde el shell y si me funciona, trae todos los objetos que he creado en el panel e administración.

Comment: Hola, ¿que tienes en tu base.html? ya que todo se ve correcto suponiendo que tienes el código de python bien indentado y tambien como estas definiendo la url?

Comment: Hola kevin gracias por tu interes, ya lo pude solucionar el problema, era que estaba colocando el nombre de la vista mal en las url.